# sum of maxima vs the maximum of the sum 

Tags: integer-programming, linear-programming

Consider the following integer program
$$
\begin{align}
\max &\sum\nolimits_{i}\sum\nolimits_{j} U_i(j)\cdot x_{i,j}\\
\text{subject to}& \sum_{i}x_{i,j}\cdot f\left(i,j\right)\leqslant c_j,& &\forall\, j\\
& x_{i,j}\in\{0,1\}.
\end{align}
$$
and the following set $\Gamma$ of integer programs ($i$ is fixed below):
$$
\begin{align}
\max &\sum\nolimits_{j} U_i(j)\cdot x_{i,j}\\
\text{subject to}& \sum_{i}x_{i,j}\cdot f\left(i,j\right)\leqslant c_j,& &\forall\, j\\
& x_{i,j}\in\{0,1\}.
\end{align}
$$
and this is done $\forall \,i$. I want to have the same results from both optimization problems(i.e. same $x_{i,j}$ from the first optimization problem and the second set and $\sum\nolimits_{i}\max\sum\nolimits_{j} U_i(j)\cdot x_{i,j}=\max\sum\nolimits_{i,j} U_i(j)\cdot x_{i,j})$

The problem is that the constraints are coupled as we can see. Consequently, the order in which the problems in $\Gamma$ are solved changes the answer. For example if we start with $i=1$ and do the maximization, we will find $x_{i,j}\, \forall j$. We can then set $c_j$ to $c_j-x_{i,j}\cdot f(i,j)$ and solve for the next $i$. But the order in which we choose the $i$'s is important. Intuitively, I am guessing that there should be an optimal order that leads to the same result. But, how can I find the optimal order? Does this problem has a well known name?

Comment: Sorry is the question unclear and that's why no one is answering? Or is it too simple? Or is it that many people are unfamiliar with this topic?

Comment: Your question has gotten over 100 views at this writing; it is liikely that over 50 MathOverflow denizens have read it.
Some subjects do not attract much interest, and your question may be one of them.  You can try editing it once a day to improve its appeal and bring it to the fore, but please make only serious content changing edits.  Providing a more specific example of the type of problem might generate more interest.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.07.10

Comment: Crossposted on MSE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167241/sum-of-maxima-vs-the-maximum-of-the-sum.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases there exists no ordering of $\Gamma$ such that solving the problems in $\Gamma$ sequentially gives the optimal value of the original problem.

Here is a simple counterexample. Let $i,j$ range from 1 to 2 and set $c_j=1, f(i,j)=1$ for all $i,j$.  Take $U_{i,j}=1$ for $i=j$ and $U_{i,j}=2$ for $i\ne j$.  Then the original problem is solved by taking $x_{1,1}=x_{2,2}=0$ and $x_{1,2}=x_{2,1}=1$, giving an objective function value of 4.  But solving $\Gamma$ in either order leads to an objective function value of 3.

Let's go through it step by step.

The problem is
$$\max x_{11} + x_{22} + 2x_{12} + 2x_{21}$$
subject to
$$x_{11}+x_{21}\le 1$$
$$x_{12}+x_{22}\le 1$$

For the other two problems, we have

$$\max x_{11} + 2x_{12}$$
subject to
$$x_{11}+x_{21}\le 1$$
$$x_{12}+x_{22}\le 1$$
which leads to **$x_{12}=1$ AND $x_{11}=1$**, in order to achieve a maximum value of 3.  Notice that **the solution to this problem in the comment below is not correct**.

Then the second problem becomes
$$\max 2x_{21} + x_{22}$$
subject to
$$x_{21}\le 0$$
$$x_{22}\le 0.$$

Comment: 
Thanks for your answer. But I have to disagree. The original problem can be formulated as follows:
$$
\begin{align}
\max & x_{1,1}+2x_{1,2}+2x_{2,1}+x_{2,2}\\
subject to & x_{1,1}+x_{2,1}\leq 1\\
& x_{1,2}+x_{2,2}\leq 1
\end{align}
$$
which indeed leads to $x_{1,2}=x_{2,1}=1$. As for the other two problems, we have:
$$
\begin{align}
\max & x_{1,1}+2x_{1,2}\\
subject to & x_{1,1}+x_{2,1}\leq 1\\
& x_{1,2}+x_{2,2}\leq 1
\end{align}
$$
which leads to $x_{1,2}=1$.

Comment: Now set $c_{2}=0$, the second problem becomes:
$$
\begin{align}
\max & 2x_{2,1}+x_{2,2}\\
\text{subject to} & x_{1,1}+x_{2,1}\leq 1\\
& x_{1,2}+x_{2,2}\leq 0
\end{align}
$$
Which leads to $x_{2,1}=1$. And the objective function is 4, same results as the first problem. Actually in this scenario the order in which you solve the problem is not important.

Comment: @john, Your solution of this problem (in comments) is not correct. I have made it completely explicit for you now.